# Issues with reading csv file with numbers and dates

Tags: r, csv

I'm doing an R assignment and I'm running into issues with my code. I've attached the question.

> Use the read csv() function to read this file into R as a data frame
> (tibble) named guitars, using the col select argument along with the
> starts with() function to omit any columns with names beginning with
> “Weight”. The entries in the columns “Purchase Price” and “Insured
> Value” should be read as numbers and the entries in the column
> “Purchase Date” should be read as dates; the remaining columns will be
> of character type. The resulting data frame should have 8 rows and 11
> columns.
>
> When you have done this part correctly, you will still receive a
> warning about “parsing issues”. State in words the cause of the
> problem.
>
> Note: Because of a bug in readr, problems(guitars) may not help you
> here, in spite of the instructions in the warning.

I wrote some code but R is producing this error code
Error:

```
unexpected '=' in:
"                      `Purchase Date` = col_date(format = ""),
                      everything() ="
```

This is my code, not sure what my problem is.

```
guitars <- read_csv(file_path, 
                col_types = cols(
                  `Purchase Price` = col_number(),
                  `Insured Value` = col_number(),
                  `Purchase Date` = col_date(format = ""),
                  everything() = col_character()
                ),
                col_select = starts_with("Weight") ~ !starts_with("Weight")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a working version, `readr::cols` has a default argument that you can set otherwise it guesses the types.

```r
read_csv(
    file_path, 
    col_types = cols(
        `Purchase Price` = "n",                     # number for specific column
        `Insured Value` = "n",                      # number for specific column
        `Purchase Date` = col_date(format = ""),    # date for specific column
        .default = "c"                              # character by default
    ),
    col_select = !starts_with("Weight") # omits columns starting with 'Weight'
)
```